# Solving the nonlinear optimization problem with the function Eig

Tags: matrices, optimization

I have the following equation:

```
Lambda=Eig(inv(M)*K)
```

where [M]n*n is a known square matrix. [K]n*n is the unknown matrix, but we know the sparsity of this matrix. K is also symmetric, and is known only if we know n elements of it (located on the diameter of the matrix). The problem is that we do not access all the elements of the vector Lambda, so that I should solve the following optimization problem to find the elements ki of the matrix K

```
arg min {Lambda- Eig(inv(M)*K)}   
   ki
```

I am confused about how I can numerically solve this problem.

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Comment: what is the 'Eig' operator?

Comment: Eigenvalues....

Comment: so Lambda is a set of eigenvalues? How do you define the difference between two sets?

Comment: Yes, Lambda is the set of eigenvalues. 
It is exactly the part that I am confused about (I do not know how to define the optimization problem).
I only know some of eigenvalues (the first 6 eigenvalues out of 14). I also have some information about Matrix K (its sparsity and the relationship between its different elements).